# Creating "intermediate" git repostory?

Tags: git

There is a project on github that I want to work on.
I cloned it and I want this clone to be base for my changes. I want this clone to become a repository itself with ability to clone it into subprojects. I want to be able to pull changes from github and then distribute those changes to subprojects and I want to be able to push changes back into github.
Hope it makes sense.

I tried to clone the github onto my machine. When I try to clone the clone, I get an error about missing "/info/refs". From what I read, I have to somehow set up my clone to be a repository. Running "git update-server-info" in my clone did not work.

I did see [Git Fatal Error: info/refs not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406963/git-fatal-error-info-refs-not-found)
They are not trying to create intermediate repo as i am trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Fatal Error: info/refs not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406963/git-fatal-error-info-refs-not-found)

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I did see this post. I believe that was a different problem with same symptoms. They did not try to create intermediate repo as I am trying to do

Comment: Are you using command-line Git? Could you copy actual commands and outputs?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look here: https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Apparently, you have not yet understood the concept of git. There is no difference between a project and a repo. Every clone has the entire history of the project and can be the base for other clones. It's also unclear what you mean by `subprojects`

Comment: Thank for the comment. That was my understanding as well -- each clone can be a "base" for other clones. Except it doe snot work. In order to be "clonable" it has to have /info/ directory with, I assume, git housekeeping stuff in it. Without this, I can not clone it. I want to take a codebase for a shopping cart, put my mods into it and then create few shops from it (subprojects). I want to be able to receive latest updates from original codebase and I want to be able to push my fixes back to community.

Comment: Then it appears that you don't have a proper clone. How did you generate the clone in the first place and how are you trying to create further clones from this? As @Melebius already said: post your commands and their outputs.

Comment: To create a clone on my machine I used: git clone

Comment: I think I may have a version mismatch and that causes issues. Initial clone is done with 2.11.0, subsequent is done with 1.7.1 Let me try to fix that first. If that fails, I will post outputs

Answer (score 0):

Version incompatibility.

I did first clone using Windows and git 2.11.0 (could not find earlier version)
Second clone was done on Linux using git 1.7.1 (it is a pain to install latest git on CentOS). That was causing issues.

I then tried to do first and second clone using same 1.7.1 and all worked like a charm.

Rudolf